# Flex Chart Sorting ColumnSeries Order

Tags: sorting, apache-flex, bar-chart, series

I am trying to create a BarChart that will display values within a ColumnSeries in an order dependant of there value.
So for instance, If I had a ColumnSeries  in a BarChart , one showing profit, the other showing expenses, it will render correctly if the profit is more than the expenses because the expenses series is rendered on top.

However, if the expenses is more than profit, the profit will not be viewable as it will be rendered underneath expenses.

At this point I am going to try and include an image to display my problem...

OK it turns out that I am not allowed to display an image :(

The image did show that profit in February is 500 but the profit of 300 in January is hidden because the Expenses of 500 is displaying over it.

You can run the code below to create the example:

```
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    [Bindable]
    public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {Month:"Jan", Profit:300, Expenses:500},
        {Month:"Feb", Profit:500, Expenses:300}
    ]);
]]></mx:Script>
<mx:Panel title="Bar Chart">
    <mx:BarChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{expenses}" showDataTips="true" type="overlaid" >
        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis  dataProvider="{expenses}" categoryField="Month" />
        </mx:verticalAxis>

        <mx:series>
            <mx:BarSeries yField="Month" xField="Profit" displayName="Profit" />
            <mx:BarSeries yField="Month" xField="Expenses" displayName="Expenses" />
        </mx:series>
    </mx:BarChart>
    <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
</mx:Panel>
```

An obvious solution to this would be to make the BarChart type 'clustered' as both values will be seen, however my client requires the BarChart to be 'overlaid', so currently some smaller values are hidden.

I would expect that there is a way to sort the order of the BarSeries but I cant seem to find how and I would really appreciate someone's superior knowledge on charting.  ;)

Comment: Try by using --->  type="stacked"

Comment: Thanks for responding Mahesh.  I have tried stacked but that adds each value together and places them on top of each other rather then infront/behind eachother

Comment: This is a situation where you should get your client to change the requirements - I don't know of any way to do what you're asking in Flex.  In order to maintain the one bar per object feel, try using a BarSeries for Profit and a PlotSeries for Expenses.  This gives the expenses more of a benchmark feel.